# Developing an application keeping toolbar and side-nav bar constant

Tags: angular

I am developing an application using Angular 7 material theme. I want to create navigation UI in which header(toolbar) and a side navigation bar will remain constant throughout the navigation of the application. Only the content of  "" should change, depending on the action menu selected from side-nav or toolbar. How to achieve this functionality?

Angular CLI version : **7.3.6**

Expected result is : After clicking any action menu from side-nav or toolbar only the content inside "" should refresh. Side-Navigation bar and toolbar should remain unchanged throughout application navigation.

[please refer the image for expected behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g24ll.jpg)

Comment: the question is too broad as it stands... do you intend to use routing? else, just change the visibility of the components as per the clicked link in your side-nav or toolbar

Comment: Yes I intend to use routing.

Comment: ok, `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` will be independent of the side-nav or toolbar... where is the hold up?

Comment: I am using several components in the application. Lets say one component per Action Menu. There's one dashboard page also. On that dashboard page I have a toolbar and sidenav bar, as shown in image attached above. 

Now, if any action menu is clicked, only the content besides the sidenav bar should change. This functionality should be throughout the application.

If I were to use <router-outlet></router-outlet>, please explain me how and where should I use it exactly!

Comment: you app.component.ts to have sidebar and router-outlet; whenever an action is clicked, you load corresponding component inside the router-outlet... if you share a stackblitz with routing, side-nav... you can share where you're stuck... the community will gladly help